# How to make a clean .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

i have problem with htaccess and not quite good at it. I want to know how to make a url clean.

Here is the original

> http://site.com/page.php?p=index1/index2

and i want this type of url

> http://site.com/page/index/index2

and how do i get the *p value* which is *index1/index2* if i what to **$_get** it from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `([^/]+)` matches everything up to but not including `/` into `$1` and the remainder is captured in `(.*)` into `$2`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite real existing files & directories (like css,js,img)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Add .php to the first group (like page.php) and stick the rest into p
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?p=$2
```

Inside of PHP, retrieve the value of `p` via:

```
$_GET['p']
```